# ColdFusion not working installed on XAMPP running Apache

Tags: apache, coldfusion, xampp

Last week I installed the latest versions of XAMPP and ColdFusion. They worked together for a while, but then I started getting a 503 "Service unavailable" when I tried to open ColdFusion .cfm files. HTML files work fine, and phpmyadmin loads, so Apache is ok. Sooo today I uninstalled and reinstalled XAMPP and then ColdFusion with today's downloads. Once again, ColdFusion worked...until it didn't. I'm not doing anything complicated. We're talking hello world kind of stuff.

Any ideas? Is there a place I can look at some log files that might give clues as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Better suited for ServerFault

Comment: What should I do? Delete and re-post? Is there a way to move?

Comment: Did you try restarting the ColdFusion server (or service)? Perhaps it stopped from inactivity (seems odd but who knows). Also, if you're open to using Railo, I would recommend looking into Vagrant. You can grab a virtual Linux server (managed by Vagrant) with Railo, Tomcat, Apache, etc. configured and ready to go for you. Best of all, you can share this with other people you want on your project without going through a major setup process on each developer machine. (http://vagrantup.com, https://vagrantcloud.com/blueriver/boxes/centos-railo-tomcat-apache)

Comment: @BrianFitzGerald -- Please add that as a response so I can accept. I had found that the CF service was off, even though it is set to automatic. When I manually restarted it, all was well. Happened again this morning -- restarted the computer and still needed to start the CF server by hand. Was planning to enter it as a solution myself.

Comment: Done, thanks. Doesn't seem like you should have to restart the computer though, even if you did need to restart the service. Anyway, I'm pleased to hear that at least you've pinned it down a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try restarting the ColdFusion server (or service)? Perhaps it stopped from inactivity (seems odd but who knows).

Also, if you're open to using Railo, I would recommend looking into Vagrant. You can grab a virtual Linux server (managed by Vagrant) with Railo, Tomcat, Apache, etc. configured and ready to go for you. Best of all, you can share this with other people you want on your project without going through a major setup process on each developer machine.

http://vagrantup.com

http://vagrantcloud.com/blueriver/boxes/centos-railo-tomcat-apache